# Trigger selecting child records, multiplying their values and updating parent record

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, mutating-table

I am a PL/SQL newbie and I'm struggling with a trigger.

Description:

I have three objects - PRODUCT, CONTAINS, ORDER. One product can have many CONTAINS and one ORDER can have many CONTAINS (basically it used to be Many-to-many relationship between PRODUCT and ORDER).

Each Product has a column "value", each CONTAINS has a column "amount" and each ORDER has a column "total".

When I add a new PRODUCT to ORDER via creating new CONTAINS, I want to recalculate field "total" on ORDER.

Example: PRODUCT X has "value" of 100. PRODUCT Y has "value" of 200. We have an ORDER O. Now I create CONTAINS between Product X and ORDER O with column "amount" of 5. Now the trigger should multiply 5 * 100 and update the ORDER column "total" to 500. Then I create CONTAINS between PRODUCT Y and ORDER O with column "amount" of 10. Now the trigger should recalculate 5 * 100 + 10 * 200 and update the "total" column on ORDER O to 2500.

My faulty trigger:

```
    create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF AMOUNT, PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT, ORDER_ID_ORDER ON CONTAINS 
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
value number;
amount number;
total number;
BEGIN
LOOP
FOR emp IN (SELECT AMOUNT, PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT, ORDER_ID_ORDER FROM CONTAINS WHERE ORDER_ID_ORDER = :n.ORDER_ID_ORDER) 
LOOP
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) into product FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID_PRODUCT = :emp.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT);
amount:= emp.AMOUNT;
total:= total + (product * amount);
UPDATE ORDER SET ORDER.TOTAL = total WHERE ID_ORDER = :n.ORDER_ID_ORDER;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

EDIT: The error shows on here:

(SELECT SUM(VALUE) into product FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID_PRODUCT = :emp.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT)

saying I can't use "emp".

EDIT2: Error message:

10/2      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe        <an alternat
10/89     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem    <an exponent (**)> and or group having intersect minus order    start union where connect || indicator multiset
15/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:     ;

Comment: Please include the actual error message you are seeing. I have an idea what it might be, but it's better for everyone if we don't have to guess.

Comment: Sorry, added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified the trigger by removing loops/cursors that isn't actually required.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF AMOUNT, PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT, ORDER_ID_ORDER 
ON CONTAINS 
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

lv_total number;

BEGIN

SELECT SUM(prdt.VALUE * :n.amount) into lv_total 
FROM PRODUCT prdt where prdt.ID_PRODUCT = :n.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT;


UPDATE ORDERs SET TOTAL = lv_total WHERE ID_ORDER = :n.ORDER_ID_ORDER;

END;
```

Refer DB Fiddle link for solution :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3be867f6ab2e93978ae45a7d305434a1

PS:Triggers can cause performance bottleneck at time when the DMLs in the triggers are not tuned well enough.Recommendation is to check the explain plan for SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE statements inside a trigger and tune them as desired.If Indexes are not available for CONTAINS.ORDER_ID_ORDER and PRODUCTS.ID_PRODUCT creating one would be beneficial but would recommend consulting with DBA in-charge.

**UPDATE :**
Now since you need to Select from the table on which trigger is fired we have to live with famous Mutating trigger error  `ORA-04091: table MYTABLE.CONTAINS is mutating, trigger/` and luckily Oracle has an easy solution for it using `Compound trigger` that was added from `Oracle Database 11g Release1` version onwards.

For more details and technical explanation on Compound Trigger you may refer http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html

Trigger Code goes like this, ta.da..
So we take rows to a pl/sql table for row operation and perform statement operation for each of the rows from the pl/sql table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger2    
FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON contains    
COMPOUND TRIGGER     

   TYPE typ_contains IS TABLE OF contains%rowtype  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;    
   tab_contains   typ_contains;    
    
   AFTER EACH ROW IS    
   BEGIN  
      tab_contains (tab_contains.COUNT + 1).amount :=    
           :NEW.amount;    
      tab_contains (tab_contains.COUNT).product_id_product := :NEW.product_id_product;
      tab_contains (tab_contains.COUNT).order_id_order := :NEW.order_id_order;
      
   END AFTER EACH ROW;    
    
   AFTER STATEMENT IS    
   lv_total number;
   
   BEGIN        
       
      FOR indx IN 1 .. tab_contains.COUNT    
      LOOP   
      
       SELECT SUM(prdt.VALUE * tab_contains(indx).amount) into lv_total 
       FROM PRODUCT prdt,contains cnts
       where cnts.order_id_order = tab_contains(indx).order_id_order 
       and prdt.id_product = cnts.product_id_product;

      UPDATE ORDERs SET TOTAL = lv_total 
      WHERE ID_ORDER = tab_contains(indx).ORDER_ID_ORDER;
                                     
      END LOOP;    
   END AFTER STATEMENT;    
END trigger2; 
/
```

Updated solution can be found in DBfiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1fb40eef7cf3a647bc5560ed19490240

Comment: Should be using ANSI join syntax.  Instead of "FROM PRODUCT prdt,CONTAINS cnts 
WHERE prdt.ID_PRODUCT = cnts.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT", use "FROM PRODUCT prdt JOIN contains cnts on prdt.ID_PRODUCT = cnts.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT"

Comment: You should change the TOTAL name. this confuses the name of the column.

Comment: @Edstevens - Thanks, modified with ANSI syntax. Just to mention that it is not mandatory to write ANSI complaint joins in SQL, it just a different syntax however there are no performance benefits. Caution :Oracle DB versions less than 11g has bugs with ANSI syntax.

Comment: One error saving changes to table "MYTABLE"."CONTAINS":
Row 7: ORA-04091: table MYTABLE.CONTAINS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Comment: I don't understand how can it be mutating if we did not update the same table we are firing the trigger from?

Comment: The advantage of ANSI join syntax is that you have to account for all tables, making it far less likely to accidentally introduce a Cartesian join.

Comment: @Edstevens - 100% agree.

Comment: @DevelBase2 - I have updated the code in case you have noticed, please check the updated code.

Comment: @VN'sCorner Thanks a lot. It does work without errors. Somehow it counts only sum of one CONTAINS record.

Example: ORDER O has 2 CONTAINS records. Each CONTAINS record has different PRODUCT record. If I make a change on one CONTAINS record, it calculates only itself. So instead of let's say Amount = 1 times Product value = 100 and other CONTAINS record has Amount 10 times Product value = 5000 which amkes together 50 100, it calculates only 1 times 100 as if the other product of the ORDER does not exist.

Comment: @DevelBase2 - Compound Trigger is one of option and works only from Oracle 11g Release 1 I have updated with code, refer UPDATE section.

Comment: If it worked,please mark/upvote the answer.If it didn't happy to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues, but the most fundamental one is that you should not be doing this at all.  Trying to store - and keep in synch - a value that can always be calculated is a fundamental design flaw.

Now, to the code itself.
You have

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) into product
```

The target of your INTO must be a declared variable.  Looks like you are trying to SELECT .. INTO  a column name.

You should name local variables to distinguish between them an column names.  Thus, instead of

```
DECLARE
value number;
amount number;
total number;
```

You should have

```
DECLARE
v_value number;
v_amount number;
v_total number;
```

Conversely, you should think about standard naming conventions for your tables and columns.  For columns I use and recommend names in the form of <adjective_noun>, thus ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, etc.  What's this with PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT, ORDER_ID_ORDER ?  Repeating the table name in the column names is usually not beneficial. Though there are times it makes sense because it still follows the adjective_noun format, like the id column of the ORDERS table being named ORDER_ID.  Think about table names also, I usually make my table names a plural noun because tables track multiple instances of some entity.  If the table name makes sense for a column name (like ORDER_ID) it would be singular, because an individual row tracks a single instance of the entity.

Lastly, it is hard to recommend coding modification without knowing the tables. You've given a vague description of them, but better to lay everything on the table. See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks alot I'll dig into it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) into product FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID_PRODUCT = :emp.PRODUCT_ID_PRODUCT
```

Instead of :emp. you should use :n.

--- UPDATE
Remove brackets in this SQL statement. You don't need them
Add variable PRODUCT
Change the name of variable TOTAL eg nTotal (it mismatch with column name)

Comment: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null...

Comment: Thanks alot, brackets and column names mismatch, got it